# Angular, get ViewChild / ViewContainerRef from dynamic created Component

Tags: angular, viewchild

is there a way to get the ViewContainerRef from a dynamic created component?
My dynamic created component has an ngContent element inside, which i want to fill after the dynamic creation.

```
export class Example {

  @ViewChild('content', { read: ViewContainerRef }) //normal way
  content: ViewContainerRef;

...

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    let box1=this.content.createComponent(this.boxFactory);
    box1.instance.title="Dynamic (1)";
    // HERE: the box1 has a ng-content area which i want to fill.
  }

}
```

I think about some manual way to resolve the ViewChild instead of using the decorators. Some Ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure as well how to add viewchild dynamically. however, if dynamic ViewContainerRef is what you want, you can try using this solution:

in the html file create:

```
  <div id="test"></div>
```

in your component create:

```
 let nodeElement = document.getElementById("test");
      let compFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);
      let component = compFactory.create(this.viewContainerRef.injector, null, nodeElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be answered if you read those two articles, it solved it for me:

https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-how-to-get-viewcontainerref-before-viewchild-query-is-evaluated-f649e51315fb

https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e

The second article contains working angular examples on Github where you can check out working examples of dynamically created Components in 4 different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically Created Component

```js
export class DashPanelComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('dashpanelpos', { read: ViewContainerRef }) dashPanelPosition?: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {  }

}
```

To access ViewContainerRef

```js
this.dashPanel = this.renderComp({}, this.contentMappings["dash_panel"], container);
this.viewContainerRef = this.dashPanel.instance["dashPanelPosition"]);
```

`dashPanelPosition` is instance of `DashPanelComponent`.