# Programmatically set attribute of dynamically added child component

Tags: angular, dynamically-generated

I have a collection of card objects

```
...
cards: Card[];
...
ngOnInit() {
  this.cardService.getCards.subscribe(r => { this.cards = r; });
}
```

I add child card components in the template like this

```
<div id="cards-container">
  <app-card *ngFor="let card of cards" [name]="card.name"></app-card>
</div>
```

The Card component has a name and some style dependant on an active attribute which is toggled by clicking the component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  'styleUrls: ['./card.component.scss']
})
export class CardComponent {
  private _name = '';
  private _active = false;

  // getters/setters
  ...

  onClick(e) {
    this.active = !this.active;
  }
}
```

card.component.html

```
<div [ngClass]="{'card': true, 'active': _active}"
     (click)="onClick($event)">
  {{name}}
</div>
```

All of this works great.

**The problem:**
In the parent component, I need to iterate through all of the card components which were added with `*ngFor="let card of cards"` and set them all active or not active but I cannot figure out how to do this.

**What I have tried:**
I tried using [`@ViewChildren()`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren#description) but the [QueryList](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList)'s `toArray()` method always gives me an empty array. From the limited examples in the [ViewChildren documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren#description) I am not 100% clear whether I need an additional Directive in the parent component or if the directives in the examples are simply used to demonstrate. So what I tried was

```
@ViewChildren(CardComponent) cardList: QueryList<CardComponent>;
```

I also tried using [ViewContainerRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#description) using something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47750947/3291390) but I was unable to make it work and it seems like that is not taking me in the right direction. I also looked at [the documentation for ComponentRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentRef) but I do not see how or if this can help me solve my problem.

Any suggestions to point me in the right direction are appreciated.

**UPDATE**

My active setter in the card component is like this

```
@Input()
set active(active: boolean) {
  this._active = active;
}
```

I need to be able to change this for all the cards at any point, in other words, a "select/deselect all" option.

**SOLVED!**

Taking the [suggestion from @Tim Klein](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55695722/3291390), I subscribed to `changes` of the QueryList and was able to get my components in an array which I update when the QueryList changes. Now I just iterate the array of components and call my `active` setter.

```
cards: CardComponent[];
@ViewChildren(CardComponent) cardList: QueryList<CardComponent>;
...
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.cards = this.cardList.toArray(); // empty array but that's okay
  this.cardList.changes.subscribe((r) => {
    this.cards = this.cardList.toArray(); // we get all the cards as soon as they're available
  });
}
```

Comment: haha i like your username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you might be facing is that once the `afterViewInit` lifecycle event is called, your dynamic components still have not loaded. Therefore, if you are calling `cardList.toArray()` inside of `afterViewInit`, it will return an empty list because your components have not been added to the parent component's view yet.

You should try to subscribe to the `changes` observable (like in [this example](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren#example-1)) and within the callback invoke your logic to alter the states of the children components.

#### Update

Another option is to simply supply another input for your child component that can accept a boolean for its active state.

Then, when you set the list of `Card` objects, simply iterate through and alter some `active` property. Simply set that property along with the `name` in the template for you parent component.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I do have an `@Input()` decorator on the `active` setter in the card component but I need to be able to "select"/"deselect" all at any point in runtime, not just when they are first added. I will update my question with a little more information.